# navigation bar states, showing and hiding the bottom nav bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Keep in mind with the following question, I am still an iOS noob.

So I understand how to hide/show/recolor the navigation bar and whatnot. My next challenge is that some screens need the nav bar and others do not.

When my app starts off, I have the nav bar as hidden and then the user can click register or log in (both of which screens have a nav bar).

So those screens have the code to show the nav bar all while the first (welcome screen) has the code to hide the nav bar.

Here is the question: Why is it that when I first start my app, the nav bar is not there, but when I go to register/login and then hit the back button to return to the welcome page (initial page) then the nav bar is still there, even though my code to hide it is in the `viewDidLoad` method?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving the logic of hidding the Nav bar to the ViewWillAppear method, you just need to override it in your View Controller class.

Alternatively I would suggest to use a separate view controller to handle your login/registration screens and only use nav bars where you need them. You would have to create a view controller in your story board with your regular screens and embed the screens that need the tab bar in a navigation controller, You can then segue from your regular view controller into the navigation controller that includes your tabs.

Hope this helps

Comment: well, there might be a better solution to my problem... see currently and originally my plan was to use swipe gestures to navigate to and from the registration screens(which was good), but the problem is that it isn't entirely intuitive for the user...any ideas?

Comment: You can achieve this by using a page view controller, just change the animation type, so it doesn't look like you are turning pages. I've used this in one of my apps for exactly the same purpose, but I've done it with vertical scrolling, just add a small label "swipe to register" or something like that.